# How are break-away point and break-in points related to damping factor 'd' of a system?

Tags: root-locus, damping-factor

I have to determine gain of P-Controller when damping factor = 1. So in the solutions it is mentioned that damping factor and break-away point are related. Please can anyone clarify how damping factor and break-away point are related?

Comment: What are break-away and break-in points? Do they have other names more commonly used?

Comment: @Andyaka In the context of PID, a *break-away point* is where the system is no longer able to maintain its current state and control action must be increased in order to prevent the system from entering undesirable states. Control action may have to be increased to keep the system from exceeding limits and/or crossing critical points. It's also known as a *"breakpoint"* or a *"break-over point."* (Double-checked a reference to make sure I wasn't off my rocker.) Context is missing from the question and P-types don't have much by way of 'states', so I'm not sure how to more forward from there.